# Binding in angularjs and typecript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using legacy angularjs 1.5 with typescript. The **data** is not getting updated in **Active User Card** when it changes in parent

**Parent**

```
<active-user-card active-users="response.activeUsers"></active-user-card>
```

**Active User Card**

```
export class ActiveUserCard {
  activeUsers: number;
  data: Array<IChartData>;

  constructor() {

    ........
    ........
    this.inactiveUsers = (totalUsers - this.activeUsers) || 0;

    this.data = [
      {name: "Active users",   y: this.activeUsers},
      {name: "Inactive users", y: this.inactiveUsers}
    ];
    ........
    ........
  }
}

angular.module('tm')
  .directive('activeUserCard', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        activeUsers: '<'
      },
      bindToController: true,
      controller: ActiveUserCard,
      controllerAs: 'auc',
      templateUrl: "./active-user-card.html"
    };
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all parent data if being used in directly in HTML then it gets reflected immediately using Angular's $watch.

But here you would want change to be reflected in **this.data** variable of your component. That you have to listen to changes and then update this.data.

```
$onChanges(changes) {
    if (changes.activeUsers&& changes.activeUsers.currentValue) {
      // update your code here
      // i don't know where totalusers are comigng in below but you just figure out.
       const inactiveUsers = (totalUsers - changes.activeUsers.currentValue) || 0;

       this.data = [
          {name: "Active users",   y: changes.activeUsers.currentValue},
          {name: "Inactive users", y: inactiveUsers}
      ];
    }
  }
```

I would recommend try to re-use code.  take out code from constructor and make method to set data which takes total users and active users as args and make data. Same method should get called from $onChanges hooks with changes.activeUsers.currentValue. So code will be clean

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, the one place you're updating `data` is the component's constructor (so, run once). Use the `$onChanges` hook.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component